# Rendering an XML value to HTML within Python-Django project

Tags: python, django

I am trying to load a value within a XML file in my project to a HTML page so that is renders in the browser. The value that I want to display is the version number of my project and it is in the format "v2.0.0". This XML file is named 'build.xml' and is contained with the 'templates/' folder in my Python-Django project. The problem I am having is that my Python code just opens the XML file when I hit the index "/" page. I want the value to be passed to the HTML.

**File:** *myproject/urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [path('', views.index, name='index')]
```

**File:** *myproject/views.py*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
#return HttpResponse('Hello, welcome to the index page.')
return HttpResponse(open('templates/build.xml').read(), content_type='text/xml')
```

**File:** *myproject/templates/build.xml*

```
<version>v2.0.0</version>
```

Comment: This is two different things. One, you want to know how you read some value out of an XML file. Two, you want to know how you want to show some value in HTML with Django. They're unrelated questions really.

Comment: And "passing a value to the HTML" sounds like you don't quite understand what you want. Do you have a HTML template already?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich - I have html templates within my /templates/ folder.